# Using Propel addCond to check if an entry is NULL

Tags: postgresql, propel

I have the following Propel condition:

```
->addCond('cond3', 're.max_person_count', Criteria::ISNULL)
```

Which yields the following error: `Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: „NULL“`

Upon closer inspection, it seems that the SQL generated is the following:

```
... (re.max_person_count=:p3 OR ...
```

Instead of the desired:

```
... (re.max_person_count IS NULL OR ...
```

Why is Propel trying to insert a value when the `Criteria` I  have chosen is `ISNULL`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using `Criteria::ISNULL` yields some unpredictable behaviour that I was not able to explain (the corresponding generated SQL tried did not map to `IS NULL`).

Here is the end result, which worked as I wished it to (in case anybody needs the question answered):

```
   $resQuery = ResQuery::create()
        ->leftJoinTable('tbl')
        ->addCond('cond1', 'tbl_id', $tableId, Criteria::EQUAL)
        ->addCond('cond2', 'canceled', 'FALSE', Criteria::EQUAL)
        ->combine(array('cond1','cond2'), 'AND', 'cond1and2')
        ->addCond('cond3', 'tbl.max_count', null)
        ->addCond('cond4', 'tbl.max_count', '0', Criteria::GREATER_THAN)
        ->addCond('cond5', 'confirmed', 'TRUE', Criteria::EQUAL)
        ->combine(array('cond4', 'cond5'), 'AND', 'cond4and5')
        ->combine(array('cond3', 'cond4and5'), 'OR', 'cond3or4and5')
        ->where(array('cond1and2', 'cond3or4and5'), 'AND')
        ->find();
```